# Surjctive,Bijective,Injective Examples

Tags: functions

Is $f : Z_9 \rightarrow Z_9$ injective, surjective, bijective och/eller inverterbar $d^{\circ}$ for

1. $f(x) = x^3 + 3*x + 7$
2. $f(x) = x^3 + 4*x + 5$
3. $f(x) = x^3 + 5*x + 4$

How should I prove it?
I think like a table but shall these values point to the same or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the easiest way to do it is to draw up a table of the values that the function $f$ takes in each case.

If all of the values 0 to 8 appear in your table, then $f$ is surjective.

If no value is repeated, then $f$ is injective.

If both, then $f$ is bijective.

Of course, the "table" method only works for (small!) finite sets, and for these sets $f$ will either be bijective, or not injective and not surjective.

Comment: Which x-values should be same?

Comment: Ah, no $x$-values will be the same, it's the $f(x)$-values that might be the same!

Comment: So it can be different x-values but same f(x)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question.   A function is said to be injective, if for every $x$ you have a different value of $f(x)$. That is, $f(x) = f(y)$ implies $x = y$

Comment: I am test for all this x-values for b example

Comment: f(x)=x^(3)+4∗x+5 .-> f(0) = 5 , f(1) = 12 , f(2)=21, f(3) = 44 , f(4) = 85 ,f(5) = 150, f(6) = 245, f(7) = 376 , f(8) = 549
Is this bijective or something like that??

Comment: That is almost correct, but you need to reduce the answers mod 9 (your function is going to $\mathbb Z_9$). So for example $f(2) = 3$, for (b)

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the tables for $x=0,1,\cdots,8$.

The function is injective if and only if all values $0,1,\cdots ,8$ appear.

Furthermore, the function is bijective if and only if it is injective if and only if it is surjective.